# Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "SSD_TOTAL_GB": request requires '300.0' and is short '50.0'. project has a quota of '250.0'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I encountered the following error while attempting to create a Google Kubernetes cluster using Terraform:

```
Error: googleapi: Error 403: Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "SSD_TOTAL_GB": request requires '300.0' and is short '50.0'. project has a quota of '250.0' with '250.0' available. View and manage quotas at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?usage=USED&project=rohan-test.
```

This error has emerged during my use of a free trial account on GCP, which grants a $300 credit. As a result, I am unable to increase the quota. Upgrading to a paid account seems to be the only solution. The Terraform script I used for creating the cluster is as follows:

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "test" {
  name                     = "primary"
  location                 = "us-central1"
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = 1
  network                  = google_compute_network.main.self_link
  subnetwork               = google_compute_subnetwork.private.self_link
  logging_service          = "logging.googleapis.com/kubernetes"
  monitoring_service       = "monitoring.googleapis.com/kubernetes"
  networking_mode          = "VPC_NATIVE"
}
```

I want to create a regional cluster, but specifying the location as zonal might enable me to create one. How can I modify the script to create a regional cluster instead of a zonal one?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this error, you can specify the node_locations within the cluster configuration in your Terraform script. Here is the modified script:

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "test" {
  name                     = "primary"
  location                 = "us-central1"
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = 1
  network                  = google_compute_network.main.self_link
  subnetwork               = google_compute_subnetwork.private.self_link
  logging_service          = "logging.googleapis.com/kubernetes"
  monitoring_service       = "monitoring.googleapis.com/kubernetes"
  networking_mode          = "VPC_NATIVE"

  # If you want a multi-zonal cluster
  node_locations = [
    "us-central1-b"
  ]
}
```

Ensure that the nodes are located within the same region as their cluster or in the region of their regional cluster if you are configuring a multi-zonal cluster. By specifying the node_locations parameter, you can manage resource allocation more effectively and avoid the quota limitations you are encountering.

Comment: How does your answer bypass quotas? You can set the location, but the quota will still apply.

Comment: @JohnHanley Although the quota limitation persists, specifying the node_location during cluster creation helps avoid encountering errors. However, even if you intend to create only one node, you still cannot surpass the quota limit. Therefore, the system would not permit you to proceed with the creation of a single node.

Comment: I still do not see how your answer solves the quota problem. You cannot bypass a quota with your answer. Your answer supports specifying the location where there is sufficient quota. I recommend you delete your answer.

Comment: the quota error we got is for underlying node and by default it is set to 3*100=300GB
and quota is 250GB correct but if we specify location in cluster and then we specify node count as only 1 it works although if you specify 3 node count by obvious it won't work it just if we want to create a regional cluster and don't care about node we must use node less than 3